# call action in controller using javascript and update view

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i have multiple selects (e.g. brands & products). I want to update the products options based on what brand the user chose. The select goes like this

```
<select asp-for="Product.BrandId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.BrandId" id="transactionBrand" onchange="brandSelect()</select>
```

i got the id of the brand that the user clicked using javascript, but what next ? i think about calling an action in a controller to get the list of products and update the viewbag on the product selection, then return to the current view. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass selected brandId to action with ajax,and action return a list,then set select options in js.Here is a working demo:
Model:

```
public class Product
    {
        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller(I use fake data to test):

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TestProduct() {
            ViewBag.BrandId = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "brand1", Value = "1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "brand2", Value = "2" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "brand3", Value = "3" } };
            ViewBag.ProductId = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "select product", Value = "" } };
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public List<SelectListItem> TestProduct(int BrandId)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> l = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "product1", Value = "1" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "product2", Value = "2" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "product3", Value = "3" } };
            return l;
        }
```

View:

```
@model xxx.xxx.Product
<select asp-for="BrandId" asp-items="ViewBag.BrandId" id="transactionBrand" onchange="brandSelect()"></select>
<select asp-for="ProductId" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductId" id="transactionProduct"></select>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        function brandSelect() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { BrandId: $("#transactionBrand").val() },
                url: 'TestProduct',
            }).done(function (data) {
                var items = '';
                $("#transactionProduct").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, Product) {
                    items += "<option value='" + Product.value + "'>" + Product.text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#transactionProduct').html(items);
                })
            
        }
    </script>
}
```

result:
[image]